# Inequality of fourier series

Tags: inequality, fourier-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ the fourier coefficient of a $2\pi-$ periodic functions $f$ we assume the regularity as we want to obtain the convergence of the series ( for example $f$ is  $C^2$)

How can i prove the inequality (if it's true)
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (a_{k}^{2}+b_{k}^{2}) \le C \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{2}-1) (a_{k}^{2}+b_{k}^{2}) $$

and what is the best constant $C\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$

Comment: don't you have $k^2-1 > 1$ for any $k>2$ ?

Comment: thanks ,  it's arrive to me to ask stupid question :) .